# Can we simplify this absolute value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking to simplify $f(\alpha,\beta)$ shown below and shading the region it represents in 2D plane.

I have that $$\beta-\alpha>0\tag1$$ $$\alpha-1>0\tag2$$

I am trying to simplify 
\begin{align}
f(\alpha,\beta)=\big|1-\beta \big|- 2\big|1-\alpha-\beta \big|-\beta-1\leq0
\end{align}

Does anyone know what $f(\alpha,\beta)$ becomes? In other words given (1) and (2), can I tell whether $1-\beta$ and $1-\alpha-\beta $ are $\geq$ or $\leq$ 0?

Thanks.

Comment: try to sum your inequalities to get something for $1-\beta$

Comment: I got $1-\beta<0$ can you think of anything else for the second one?, if not how shall I proceed?

Comment: well for the second use the fact that $\alpha >1$ so that $1-\beta>1-\beta-\alpha$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\beta-\alpha\gt 0,\ \alpha-1\gt 0\Rightarrow  (\beta-\alpha)+(\alpha-1)\gt 0$$
and that 
$$\beta\gt\alpha\gt 1\gt 0,\ \alpha-1\gt0\Rightarrow \beta+(\alpha-1)\gt 0.$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the second condition?

Comment: Since we have $\beta-\alpha\gt 0$, we have $\beta\gt\alpha$. Since we have $\alpha-1\gt 0$, we have $\alpha\gt 1$. Thus we have $\beta\gt \alpha\gt 1$.

Comment: Thanks I have one more question,if you dont mind, if I have that  $\beta-\alpha>0$ but $\alpha-1>0$ can I say something about the same absolute values $|1-\alpha-\beta|$ and $|1-\beta|$?

Comment: @Tyrone: Since $\beta-1\gt 0$ and $\alpha+\beta-1\gt 0$, we have $1-\beta\lt 0$ and $1-\alpha-\beta\lt 0$. Thus, we have $|1-\beta|=-(1-\beta)$ and $|1-\alpha-\beta|=-(1-\alpha-\beta)$.

Comment: Sorry, I had typo, I meant to type that we only have that $\beta-\alpha>0$, but $\alpha-1<0$ can I say somethhing about $|1-\beta|$ and $|1-\alpha-\beta|$?

Comment: @Tyrone: If we have $\beta-\alpha\gt 0$ and $\alpha-1\color{red}{\lt} 0$, then $1-\beta$ and $1-\alpha-\beta$ can be both positive and negative.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your inequalities (just pass $1$, respectively $\alpha$, on the other side) to get $1<\alpha<\beta$ and note that $0>1-\beta> 1-\beta-\alpha$.